# How to make textView that is set dynamically appear when Tab is run?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, textview

Let me try to explain my question in detail.
I have 5 tabs and my Tab class is run after the Splash screen of my application, and the first tab will be displayed.

In my first tab, I have a class that contains a TextView that will display certain text under some condition (related to profile keyed in by the user in another class).

```
TextView duration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
duration.setText(durationNumber);

if(week <= 12)
{
durationNumber = "Less than 12 weeks";
}

else 
{
durationNumber = "More than 12 weeks";
}
```

When I run my application, the text does not appear, unless i navigate to other tabs and return to the first tab. I googled around and couldn't find a solution. I've tried using SharedPreferences but it didn't work. Perhaps I did it wrongly.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the initial value of `durationNumber`? Is it `null` before it is set in the if-else loop? If it is `null` then the TextView will not appear (as there is no value to display).

You will have to set the `TextView` text again after the if-else loop. Try this...

```
TextView duration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
if(week <= 12) {
   durationNumber = "Less than 12 weeks";
} else {
   durationNumber = "More than 12 weeks";
}
duration.setText(durationNumber);
```

Comment: Yeah it worked! I didn't think of that. Well explained and thanks a lot @neo108!

Comment: No worries @HoneyH. Enjoy coding :-)